# Tensor Product Question in Kassel's Quantum Groups

Tags: tensor-products, quantum-groups, hopf-algebras

In Kassel's book on Quantum Groups, I am stuck on the following computation:

\begin{eqnarray*}
[\Delta (E), \Delta (F)] &=& \Delta (E)\Delta (F)-\Delta (F)\Delta (E)\\
&=& (1\otimes E + E \otimes K) (K^{-1} \otimes F + F\otimes 1)\\
&&-(K^{-1}\otimes F+F\otimes 1)(1\otimes E+E\otimes K)\\
&=& K^{-1}\otimes EF + F\otimes E + EK^{-1}\otimes KF + EF\otimes K\\
&&-K^{-1}\otimes FE - K^{-1}E\otimes FK - F\otimes E - FE\otimes K\\
&=& K^{-1} \otimes (EF-FE) + (EF-FE) \otimes K\\
&=& K^{-1}\otimes [E,F] + [E,F]\otimes K\\
&=& \frac{K^{-1}\otimes (K-K^{-1})+(K-K^{-1})\otimes K}{q-q^{-1}}\\
&=& \frac{K\otimes K-K^{-1}\otimes K^{-1}}{q-q^{-1}}\\
&=& \frac{\Delta (K)-\Delta (K^{-1})}{q-q^{-1}}
\end{eqnarray*}

The above computation was attempted by me, but I am not sure of one part, namely why is 
$EK^{-1}\otimes KF = -(K^{-1}E\otimes FK )$.

I understand that $E,F,K$ are variables that generate the quantum group $U_q(\mathfrak{sl}(2))$.

Sincere thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a sign error we have $EK^{-1}\otimes KF=K^{-1}E\otimes FK$. This is because of the following two relations:
\begin{align*}
KEK^{-1}&=q^2E\\
KFK^{-1}&=q^{-2}F
\end{align*}
Hence we have
\begin{align*}
EK^{-1}=q^2K^{-1}E\\
KF=q^{-2}FK
\end{align*}
This gives the above equality (since $q^2q^{-2}=1$ and you can put scalars in front of the tensor product).

Otherwise your computation is correct.